# python combine lists with order

Tags: python

I have two question about combine lists
Please guide me Thank you.

Here is my code :

```
product['image_urls'] =  [
    "http://A.jpg",
    "http://B.jpg",
    "http://C.jpg" ]

product['image'] = [{
        "url" : "http://A.jpg",
        "path" : "full/1.jpg",
        "checksum" : "cc76"},
    {
        "url" : "http://B.jpg",
        "path" : "full/2.jpg",
        "checksum" : "2862"},
    {
        "url" : "http://C.jpg",
        "path" : "full/3.jpg",
        "checksum" : "6982"}]
```

And I write this :

```
for url in product['image_urls']:
    for info in product['image']:
        print url,info['url'],info['path'],info['checksum']
```

The result is :

```
http://A.jpg  http://A.jpg  full/1.jpg  cc76
http://A.jpg  http://B.jpg  full/2.jpg  2862
http://A.jpg  http://C.jpg  full/3.jpg  6982
http://B.jpg  http://A.jpg  full/1.jpg  cc76
http://B.jpg  http://B.jpg  full/2.jpg  2862
http://B.jpg  http://C.jpg  full/3.jpg  6982
http://C.jpg  http://A.jpg  full/1.jpg  cc76
http://C.jpg  http://B.jpg  full/2.jpg  2862
http://C.jpg  http://C.jpg  full/3.jpg  6982
```

But what I want is this

```
http://A.jpg  http://A.jpg  full/1.jpg  cc76     
http://B.jpg  http://B.jpg  full/2.jpg  2862     
http://C.jpg  http://C.jpg  full/3.jpg  6982
```

because I want to store to db like `Image.objects.create(article=id,image_urls=url,url=info['url'],path=info['path'],checksum=info['checksum'])`

How can I combine them to reach it??

And My second question is , you can see the `product['image_urls']` and the `product['image']['url']` is the same.
But sometimes the `product['image']` would have empty value(because it failed when catching the image) like :

```
product['image_urls'] =  [
    "http://A.jpg",
    "http://B.jpg",
    "http://C.jpg" ]

product['image'] = [{
        "url" : "http://A.jpg",
        "path" : "full/1.jpg",
        "checksum" : "cc76"},
        {
        "url" : "http://C.jpg",
        "path" : "full/3.jpg",
        "checksum" : "6982"}]
```

So if I just zip them ,it will save wrong data to database like this because `"url" : "http://B.jpg",` is missing :

```
[('http://A.jpg', {'url': 'http://A.jpg', 'path': 'full/1.jpg', 'checksum': 'cc76'}),   ('http://B.jpg', {'url': 'http://C.jpg', 'path': 'full/3.jpg', 'checksum': '6982'})]
```

Please teach me how to combine them ??
Thank you a lot

Comment: What do you want the output to look like in the final example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each item in the first list, you want to print only if the corresponding item in the second list exists.

We build a temporary dictionary, keyed by the items from the first list, and consult it when printing:

```
# "images" will contain exactly the same info as "product['image']", but
# keyed by the URL.
images = { d['url']:d for d in product['image'] }

# Print every line implied by the first data set
for url in product['image_urls']:
    # But only if the data is actually in the second data set
    if url in images:
        image = images[url]
        print url, image['url'], image['path'], image['checksum'] 
        # Or ...
        # Image.objects.create(article=id,
        #                      image_urls=url, 
        #                      url=image['url'],
        #                      path=image['path'],
        #                      checksum=image['checksum'])
        # Or fancier,
        # Image.objects.create(article=id, images_urls=url, **image)
```